# WinSock returning SOCKET_ERROR for no apparent reason

Tags: c++, winsock2

I'm learning basic network programming with WINSOCK. The server builds and executes just fine except for that it doesn't get past bind() which returns SOCKET_ERROR.

output: "Error: SOCKET_ERROR (-1)"

code:

```
#pragma once
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma comment (lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

SOCKET NewConnection;

bool ListenForConnection(int PORT, std::string IP)
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    int wsa_error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);
    if (wsa_error)
    {
        std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    if (wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202)
    {
        std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN IncomingClient;
    IncomingClient.sin_family = AF_INET;
    IncomingClient.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, IP.c_str(), &(IncomingClient));

    NewConnection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    if (NewConnection == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << NewConnection << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    if (bind(NewConnection, (LPSOCKADDR)&IncomingClient, sizeof(IncomingClient) == SOCKET_ERROR))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: SOCKET_ERROR (-1)" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    listen(NewConnection, SOMAXCONN);

}



int main()
{
    int PORT = 1337;
    std::string IP = "0.0.0.0";
    ListenForConnection(PORT, IP);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to use INADDR_ANY instead of 0.0.0.0 and check that the port is not already used otherwise change the value and try again

Comment: already tried, to no effect.

Comment: Different ports don't work either, I've tried several now.

Comment: @Raindrop7: `INADDR_ANY` and `0.0.0.0` are the same thing when binding a socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, IP.c_str(), &(IncomingClient));
```

`inet_pton` expects a `IN_ADDR`, not the `SOCKADDR_IN` that has been provided. `SOCKADDR_IN` contains a `IN_ADDR`, so OP needs to make the call a little differently to provide a pointer to the `sin_addr` member:

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, IP.c_str(), &(IncomingClient.sin_addr));
```

Then they need to sort out a few other problems like the missing `return true;` at the end of `ListenForConnection`, the misplaced bracket

```
                                                                         This bracket here V
if (bind(NewConnection, (LPSOCKADDR)&IncomingClient, sizeof(IncomingClient) == SOCKET_ERROR))
                                                            should be here ^
```

and not checking the return code of

```
listen(NewConnection, SOMAXCONN);
```

and they should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, grade A help :)!